# Eu estou tentando inserir um nome e depois o reproduzir, mas quero fazer com que só seja possível colocar letras

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Exer {

    String name1;

    public void name1() {
        String name1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Por favor informe um nome");
        try {
            System.out.println("Nome:" + name1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Inválido:" + name1);
            this.name1();
        }
    }
public static void main(String args[]) {
        Exer e = new Exer();
        e.name1();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o seguinte como exemplo:

```
String entrada;
        String nome = "";
        do {
            entrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe seu nome: ");
            if (entrada.matches("^[a-zA-Z]*$")) {
                nome = entrada;
                System.out.println("Seu nome é: "+ nome);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Por favor, informe um nome válido: );
            }
        } while (!entrada.matches("^[a-zA-Z]*$")
```